# compare quantity of each item against quantity entered by user in form with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have form with checkbox for each item and quantity as input value. Need to check quantity of each listed item in mysql db and process further:

Code is as below:

```
<?php
If(isset($_REQUEST['submit1'])!='') {

$itm=$_POST['itm'];
$odate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($itm);$i++) {
$rqty=$_POST['rqty'];

$qtysql = mysql_query("SELECT qty FROM $table WHERE itemname = '$itm[$i]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qtysql)) {
$aqty=$row['qty'];
if ($rqty > $aqty) {
echo "<h3><font color='red'>Available qty: ". $aqty ." Enter less Quantity</h3></font><p>";
} else {
$sql1="update $table set qty=qty - $rqty[$i] where itemname='$itm[$i]'";
$query = mysql_query($sql1);
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Above code gives error if entered qty is greater than available quantity which is OK. But it gives same error even if entered quantity is lesser than available quantity which is incorrect. It should update the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `$rqty` variable is array (you use `$rqty[$i]`) and

```
if ($rqty > $aqty)
```

here use as integer. Try like this:

```
if ($rqty[$i] > $aqty)
```

Comment: Noticed that and changed. Thanks anyway.